# How to calculate the position to be to see ISS passing in front of the moon or the sun?

Tags: the-sun, the-moon, photography, iss

I would like to know how to calculate the time/date of the ISS passing in front of the moon (between the observer and the moon) or the sun, or to calculate the position in which the observer have to be to see the ISS passing in front of the moon/sun.

Th goal is to make a photograph of the ISS in the moon/sun.

Is it possible with tools such as Stellarium?

[image]

Comment: [ISS Transit Finder](https://transit-finder.com/) may help.

Comment: @MikeG Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was searching for. Put it in an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ISS Transit Finder](https://transit-finder.com/) offers such predictions up to 30 days ahead.
If a query yields no transits at the specified location,
the "Show on Map" button for a close pass shows where a transit would be visible.
As the [documentation](https://transit-finder.com/help) notes,
predictions beyond 10 days are rather uncertain.

Recent versions of Stellarium can show ISS's apparent position at a given place and time,
offering an alternative prediction for any given event.